# Writing a string including variables to File in Python

Tags: python, file

I have a program that runs well using the print statement to display on screen. now I would like to create a txt or csv file with the same information. rings is a int that is at the start of the program, angle and segment_length are calculated floats.

```
f = open("segcalc.csv", "a")
f.write("ring: str(rings), angle str(angle), length str(segment_length,\n")
f.close
```

This is the output that is presented on the screen

```
D:\pythonProject\Segments\venv\Scripts\python.exe D:/pythonProject/Segments/SegCalc.py
Enter the number of rings for this project.3
Enter the number of segments for this ring.16
Enter the outside diameter of the ring.5
Diameter 5.0 Angle 11.25 Length 0.98175
Enter the number of segments for this ring.16
Enter the outside diameter of the ring.6
Diameter 6.0 Angle 11.25 Length 1.1781
Enter the number of segments for this ring.16
Enter the outside diameter of the ring.7
Diameter 7.0 Angle 11.25 Length 1.37445
That's All Folks

Process finished with exit code 0
```

The output to the file looks like this.

```
ring: str(rings)     angle str(angle)    length str(segment_length
ring: str(rings)     angle str(angle)    length str(segment_length
ring: str(rings)     angle str(angle)    length str(segment_length
```

Any help greatly appreciated

Comment: Have a look at the [csv module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html)

Comment: Or maybe you want [f-strings](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html): `"f.write(f"ring: str({rings}), angle str({angle}), length str({segment_length},\n")` ??

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can tell you just need to format the string: if you are new to formatting, it just means putting a placeholder in the spot for your future input or when a value needs to be calculated (at runtime).

as an example you want to display a value for x, write the code in advance:

```
x = input("enter value for x")
```

now I want to print this variable; I must write a print statement beforehand, without knowing what x will be.

```
print(x)  # is an option; will display: x
print('{}'.format(x)) # is an option; will also display: x
print('{}',x) # is an option
print(f'{x}') # is also an option
```

now all the options within the print() statement are formatted string. The best thing is you can also use formatted strings outside print functions.

```
x = 1.45
y = f"we're using formatted string to display this {x} in the middle of the sentence"
```

now we print this

```
print(y)
-> we're using formatted string to display this 1.45 in the middle of the sentence
```

as you can see; you can store formatted sentences in a variable name.

coming back to your question to store this in a file.

you can store every question and answer together in a variable

```
with open("segcalc.csv", "a") as f:
    question = "Enter the number of rings for this project. "
    y = input(question)
    x = f"{question} {y}\n" 
     OR 
    x = "{} {}\n".format(question , y)
    # \n is for entering a new line after your sentence when printing.

    # and write this line to your .txt or .csv
    f.write(x)
```